# What is bothering Esther today?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Today is Tanis Esther, the day of Esther's "Taynos", which means claims or argument. What are Esther's claims?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: I have a good answer to why we fast today for a serious question, but that would not work for this purim torah question.

Comment: @sabbahillel remember that you can ask and answer a question -- just make sure the question is a complete question and not just a hook for your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The complaints that Esther had then are the same ones as today.

Then, Persians wanted to get rid of Jews. Today, it is the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Esther was upset because all the children stayed home from school because the teachers all went out to fight. She had to help entertain the younger children while keeping the older children from joining their fathers and older brothers who were risking their lives.

Comment: +1 for clever answer. You do realize, though, that the original Ta'anit Esther was on a day that was very different from the current date used?

Comment: @DanF  Yes I know. I am referring to the fact that the Bnai Yisrael would fast when they went to war. Also the current Taanis Esther is the day that we fought rather than the three days that Esther asked for before she went to Achashveros.